# avplayer timeshift

Tags: objective-c, ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

in our streaming server we are caching the live streams up to 3 hours and when i stream the url with movieplayerviewcontroller the time scrubber can go back to 3 hours however I couldn't find a way to implement this in avplayer. could anyone point me the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this method myself, but I would look at AVPlayer's `seekToTime` method mentioned in Apple's documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009530-CH1-SW42).

Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following :
**player** - AVPlayer, **newTime** - From were to start

```
player.seek(to: newTime, toleranceBefore: kCMTimeZero, toleranceAfter: kCMTimeZero)
```